# Many to many relationship null check

Tags: .net, .net-core, ef-core-6.0

I have 2 entities in relationship many to many.

1st one **Offer**

```
public class Offer
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [MaxLength(128)]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public virtual ICollection<ProfessionalExperience> ProfessionalExperiences { get; set; }
...
   }
```

2nd one **ProfessionalExperience**

```
    public class ProfessionalExperience
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [MaxLength(50)]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Offer>? Offers { get; set; }

    }
```

While creating the new offer I see that it is possible to create new offer without Professional Experiences although it's marked as Required.

Is there a way I can enforce null check on database or EF level? If not do you think that adding check on ViewModel would be enought?

Comment: "Collections" are never null in relational databases. They can be empty (Count = 0) or have elements (Count >= 1). There is no way to enforce non empty collection in database.

Comment: Which means: you need some sort of custom validation logic to enforce > 0 `ProfessionalExperiences`.

Comment: Sorry to hear that... anyway Thanks guys for help